# rspec + carrierwave : Images are not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I have this spec :

```
post :create, :room_id => @room.id, :image => Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(path, 'text/jpg')
response.should redirect_to admin_room_path(@room)

@room.reload.pictures.count.should == 1
pic = @room.pictures.first

File.open(pic.image.url).should == File.open(path)
# Not working
```

It fails with the following error :

```
1) Admin::PicturesController should fail to upload a new picture
     Failure/Error: File.open(pic.image.url).should == File.open(path)
     Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory - /uploads/picture/image/5134d0fa93ff007fcd000016/image1.jpg
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/pictures_controller_spec.rb:26:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/pictures_controller_spec.rb:26:in `open'
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/pictures_controller_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The file is not found, however, the directory `/uploads/picture/image/5134d0fa93ff007fcd000016/` is created.

Everything except the file is correct.

My initializer :

```
if Rails.env.test? or Rails.env.cucumber?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = true
  end
end
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pic.image.url` is a URL path without the host.

Try:

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "public", pic.image.url)).should == File.open(path)
```

Or, my preference, let carrierwave deal with it:

```
File.open(pic.image.path).should == File.open(path)
```

Or compare content:

```
pic.image.read.should == File.open(path).read
```

Comment: ``No such file or directory - /Users/Intrepidd/git/xxxx/uploads/picture/image/5134e3ff93ff005583000030/image1.jpg``

Comment: And for the second: ``invalid byte sequence in UTF-8``